# Azure Function App HTTP Trigger CosmosDB input query from the request's body

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have created an Azure Function that gets triggered with an HTTP POST request.
The request has a body like the following:

```json
{
    "start": '2018-07-25T08:47:16.094Z',
    "end": '2018-07-25T08:47:24.686Z'
}
```

**index.js**

```js
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    var inputDocument = context.bindings.inputDocument;
    context.log("INPUT DOCUMENT: " + JSON.stringify(inputDocument));
    context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: "OK",
        };
};
```

**function.json**

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "inputDocument",
      "databaseName": "Messages",
      "collectionName": "Collection1",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM Collection1 c WHERE c.message.timestamp>={start} AND c.message.timestamp<={end}",
      "connectionStringSetting": "cosmosdbaccount_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to query a CosmosDB instance with these two parameters like this:

```
"sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM Collection1 c WHERE c.message.timestamp>={start} AND c.message.timestamp<={end}",
```

Doing it like I show here results in the CosmosDB's inputBinding beeing undefined.

```
2018-12-13T08:19:54.332 [Information] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=af8090a4-5fab-4fbd-b26f-a045d8900d9b)
2018-12-13T08:19:56.704 [Information] JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2018-12-13T08:19:56.711 [Information] INPUT DOCUMENT: []
2018-12-13T08:19:56.755 [Information] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=af8090a4-5fab-4fbd-b26f-a045d8900d9b)
```

If I run the same exact query replacing `start` and `end` with the correct ISO timestamps in the CosmosDB Data Explorer it returns all four documents.

Am I missing something? I really didn't find anything about this topic online so I hope someone has already stumbled upon it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty result seems expected for now. In CosmosDB bingding, `sqlQuery` has difficulty handling nested token(`start` and `end` are properties of request body), [related issue here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1726).

Here are three workarounds to try.

1. Simply put `start` and `end` in query string, like `https://functionUrl?start=<timeA>&end=<timeB>`.
2. In `function.json`, set route parameter `start` and `end`, i.e. add `"route": "{start}/{end}",` in httpTrigger binding. Then put time in url to visit.
3. Get request body and [query CosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-get-started#Query) on our own.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Very detailed but concise, I will probably go for the third option since it's the most flexible but the other two are very good too, thanks again!