# Azure function in node.js with Cosmos DB binding doesn't get properties injected into sqlQuery

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following configuration.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": ["post"],
      "route": "migrate/events/"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "name": "documents",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "direction": "in",
      "databaseName": "MyDatabase",
      "collectionName": "{name}",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c where c._ts >= {ts} ORDER BY c._ts OFFSET 0 LIMIT 3",
      "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDBConnection"
    },
    ...
}
```

And I call the endpoint with the following request body.

```
{
    "name": "MyEvents",
    "ts": 1620712053
}
```

In the function, I can see that the properties are available on the `req.body` but the `documents` array is empty.

Replacing the `{ts}` property with the actually value gives an array of 3 documents.

```
"sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c where c._ts >= 1620712053 ORDER BY c._ts OFFSET 0 LIMIT 3",
```

Hence, it works for the `collectionName` where `{name}` is injected but not for `sqlQuery` where `{ts}` should be injected.

I've also tried using routedata `"route": "migrate/events/{name}/{ts}"` and query `{Query.ts}` but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question before, Currently this is prevented in bindings on the **`sqlQuery`**. As mentioned [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/4fabead81601aef32f87067dd7cb60bbf86681db/README.md#sql-query-support)

> "In order to prevent injection attacks, any binding string used in the
> SqlQuery property is replaced with a SqlParameter before being sent to
> your Document DB database. "

You can follow this alternative [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747922/azure-function-app-http-trigger-cosmosdb-input-query-from-the-requests-body),

Comment: I've already tried using route and query parameters without any luck.